# Implementing an asynchronous iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Per [PEP-492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for) I am trying to implement an asynchronous iterator, such that I can do e.g.

```
async for foo in bar:
    ...
```

Here is a trivial example, similar to the one in the docs, with a very basic test of instantiation and async iteration:

```
import pytest

class TestImplementation:
    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
    async def __anext__(self):
        raise StopAsyncIteration


@pytest.mark.asyncio  # note use of pytest-asyncio marker
async def test_async_for():
    async for _ in TestImplementation():
        pass
```

However, when I execute my test suite, I see:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________________ test_async_for ________________________________

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_async_for():
>       async for _ in TestImplementation():
E       TypeError: 'async for' received an invalid object from __aiter__: TestImplementation

...: TypeError
===================== 1 failed, ... passed in 2.89 seconds ======================
```

Why does my `TestImplementation` appear to be invalid? As far as I can tell it meets the protocol:

> 1. An object must implement an `__aiter__` method ... returning an asynchronous iterator object.
> 2. An asynchronous iterator object must implement an `__anext__` method ... returning an awaitable.
> 3. To stop iteration `__anext__` must raise a `StopAsyncIteration` exception.

This is failing with the latest released versions of Python (3.5.1), `py.test` (2.9.2) and `pytest-asyncio` (0.4.1).

Comment: Works for me with pytest 2.9.2. What version are you using?

Comment: @MikeMüller `pytest-2.8.5` and `asyncio-0.3.0` plugin, will see if an upgrade helps things...

Comment: @MikeMüller nope, same outcome with `pytest-2.9.2` and `asyncio-0.4.1` plugin

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.1.

Comment: Fails for me in the exact same manner using the latest of both with 3.5.0. works with 3.6 .

Comment: Possibly related to: http://bugs.python.org/issue27243

Comment: @MikeMüller I still couldn't get 3.5.1 to work with the original code, had to add an `async` as shown below...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the above will start to work in 3.5.2 (tomorrow!) and 3.6.x, it's only the first two patch releases of 3.5.x that fail...

Comment: It worked for me with Python 3.5.1 because I didn't have `pytest-asyncio` installed at all. ;).  At least it got you stared on the wrong-version-search path. :)  After installing  `pytest-asyncio`, I can reproduce your problem and your solution.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you read [a little further down the documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#why-aiter-does-not-return-an-awaitable) it mentions that (emphasis mine):

> PEP 492 was accepted in CPython 3.5.0 with `__aiter__` defined as a
>   method, that was expected to return **an awaitable resolving to an
>   asynchronous iterator**.
>
> In 3.5.2 (as PEP 492 was accepted on a provisional basis) the
>   `__aiter__` protocol was updated to return asynchronous iterators directly.

Therefore for versions prior to 3.5.2 (released 2016/6/27) the documentation is slightly out of step with how to write a working asynchronous iterator. The fixed version for 3.5.0 and 3.5.1 looks like:

```
class TestImplementation:
    async def __aiter__(self):
  # ^ note
        return self
    async def __anext__(self):
        raise StopAsyncIteration
```

This was introduced on closing [bug #27243](http://bugs.python.org/issue27243) and is a little clearer in the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#asynchronous-iterators), which also suggests a way of writing backwards compatible code.

Answer (score 4):

Asynchronous iterators have been implemented in Python 3.6 - see [PEP-525](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/)

Then you don't need your TestImplementation at all in order to use `async for`. You can just use `yield` (example taken from PEP-525):

```
async def ticker(delay, to):
    """Yield numbers from 0 to `to` every `delay` seconds."""
    for i in range(to):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
```

You can then use `async for` as you would expect:

```
async for i in ticker(1, 10):                                                                     
    print(f'Tick #{i}')
```

Comment: This is a generator which is not the same thing as an iterator.  Not all iterators can be refactored into generators, nor should they be.  The point of the OP's question was to create an iterator, not test an `async for` loop.