# Mixed comprehension (async + sync) does not work as expected in Python

Tags: python, async-await, iterator, list-comprehension, python-asyncio

I am trying to make my code better by omitting mutable list and replacing comprehension. There is a nested 'for' iterator which the inner is async. Here is the working code:

```
async def get_accumulator_providers(order: OrderDTO) -> Tuple[str, ...]:
    bucket_mapping = await read_config(order)
    result = []
    for bucket in bucket_mapping:
        async for item in dispatch_bucket(order, bucket, bucket_mapping[bucket], frozenset(accumulator_filters)):
            result.append(item)
    return tuple(result)
```

But when I use this code instead:

```
async def get_accumulator_providers(order: OrderDTO) -> Tuple[str, ...]:
    bucket_mapping = await read_config(order)

    return tuple(item for bucket in bucket_mapping async for item in
             dispatch_bucket(order, bucket, bucket_mapping[bucket], frozenset(accumulator_filters)))
```

I get this error:

```
 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

What is the problem with my nested comprehension?

Comment: Maybe I will say something obvious but can it be because `async for` creates an `async_generator` object, that cannot be passed to `tuple()`, as it is not iterable?

Comment: Have you tried `tuple([item for ... async for ...])` instead? This should potentially work, as it is a list comprehension and not a generator expression.

Comment: Sync and async iterators use different protocols. Make `read_config(order)` return an `async` iterator and let both `for` loops be `async`. See [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031066/implementing-an-asynchronous-iterator)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `tuple` uses synchronous iterator protocol.

Yuru Selivanov answered [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue32113):

> > ...     result = list(await g(i) for i in range(3))
>
> This is equivalent to this code:
>
> ```
>  async def ait():
>      for i in range(3):
>          v = await g(i)
>          yield v
>
>  result = list(ait())
> ```
>
> Where `ait` is an async generator function.  You can't iterate it with the  regular `for x in ...` syntax, and you can't pass it to functions that expect a synchronous iterator (such as `list`).
>
> Similarly, with synchronous code:
>
> ```
>  a = (i for i in range(3))
>  a[0]
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>  TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
> ```
>
> where (`for ...`) is another syntax for defining a synchronous generator.
>
> > ...     `result = [await g(i) for i in range(3)]`
>
> This is equivalent to this code:
>
> ```
>  result = []
>  for i in range(3):
>      v = await g(i)
>      result.append(v)
> ```
>
> I agree that PEP 530 is a bit vague about this and can be updated.  I'll take a look into that.
>
> Perhaps we can make the "TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable" error message a bit clearer.  Any ideas to improve it are welcome.
>
> > I would say that the first case should either behave as a second one, or raise a syntax error.
>
> No, but we can improve error messages.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned @VisioN and I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285419/aggregating-an-async-generator-to-a-tuple), the problem is not mixing async and sync for loops. The problem is using tuple() for joining iterations. Using a [] as list comprehension fixed the problem. Actually, tuple() is not list comprehension but just gets a generator and calls 'iter' for making a tuple. Therefore, the following code works:

```
async def get_accumulator_providers(order: OrderDTO) -> Tuple[str, ...]:
bucket_mapping = await read_config(order)

return tuple([item for bucket in bucket_mapping async for item in
         dispatch_bucket(order, bucket, bucket_mapping[bucket], frozenset(accumulator_filters))])
```